# Tinymce localization 2-letter code

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

According to https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/localization/ I need to write `language: 'fr_FR'` in order to localize in French language.

Is it possible tow use 2-letter code `fr`?

I want to write `language : 'fr'`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this (as opposed to just using the code TinyMCE wants you to use) you can do all of the following:

1. Download the french localization file from the TinyMCE web site (https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/)
2. Place this file in the langs folder within your TinyMCE files
3. Rename the file from `fr_FR.js` to `fr.js`
4. Open the `fr.js` file and change the first line from `tinymce.addI18n('fr_FR',{` to `tinymce.addI18n('fr',{`

This seems like a lot of work as opposed to just using the string TinyMCE wants you to use in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
language: 'fr_FR`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way from their documentation.
It seems like you have two options.

1. Use a variable equal to the string 'fr_FR'.

   `var fr = 'fr_FR';`
2. Use a `language_url` instead and point to the absolute location of the file.

Comment: I didn't understand the first option. Second option works, but I need to use language variable.

Comment: The first option you are creating a variable equal to 'fr_FR' and using that variable in the init like `language: fr`.

Comment: I need to use string 'fr'.